# How likely can a Bluetooth IC get damaged if the antenna has a wide bandwidth?

Tags: rf, emc, bluetooth-low-energy

I design a device with a Bluetooth low energy chip (DA14863) that sits at different positions on the human body (minimal distance of 0.7mm). Simulation shows that the human body absorbes up to 95% of the radiated power what is obviously not great but acceptable. However, what could prevent the transmission is the detuning of the antenna due to the different positions on the human body. That's why we need a broadband antenna with e.g. a bandwidth of 600 MHz with S11_magnitude < -6dB. How realistic is it that such a broadband antenna captures a (broadband)-signal that damages the RF-input of the chip?

Typical Bluetooth antennas have a narrow bandwidth of about 150 MHz. So it's not only an antenna, but also a filter. I guess that helps to protect the RF input of the IC. Is the power level of signals close to the ISM band anyway typically lower in the consumer space? For EMC, can the immunity to radiated signals get an issue?

In the datasheet, I found "blocker power level". It's defined for different frequency bands, e.g.: 30 MHz <= fBL <= 2399 MHz; PWANTED = -67dBm; PBL_I_ble_min = -5 dBm. I guess that means that any signal with f < 2400 MHz with a power smaller than -5 dBm is acceptable for a successful transmission? I could not find any info when the RF-input could get damaged though.

Comment: It's probably not the ISM band you have to worry about, but radiolocation, military etc. And the 2.4GHz band itself, since it is filled to the brim with crap. As for EMC, check out EN/ETSI 300 328 v2.2.2. It's available for free from ETSI.

Comment: EN 300 328 is indeed interesting: 4.3.1.2.3 / 4.3.2.2.3 RF output power for FHSS and non-FHSS equipment < 20 dBm. 4.3.2.3.3 The maximum Power Spectral Density for non-FHSS equipment is 10 dBm per MHz. It applies certainly to EU with RED 3.2, FCC 15.247 seems the equivalent (with slightly different limits) in the US.

Comment: Supposedly these should be somewhat well harmonized world-wide for the 2.4GHz band.